# Not able to Bind angular expression in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I am facing some problem with compatibility of my angularJS application and IE. I have this in Html:

```
<div>{{somefunction(somevalue)}}</div>
```

and I have some function like this in my controller:

```
$scope.somefunction = function(value){
    return value.toUpperCase();
}
```

Now in my google chrome I get to see the proper value.

like if the value is World, I get to see WORLD, but in IE i get to see **{{somefunction(value)}}**

please help me with a solution

PS: I am not able to share a plunker as it works fine in both IE and chrome when done in plunker or any other alikes

Comment: Which version of IE.? Also check consle and confirm if there any bug.

Comment: no there is not bug, and IE version is 11

Comment: add this in root html file: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" /> Let me know if it work`

Comment: Problem might be somewhere else. Like on how you produce that somevalue in your code.

Comment: I will just try that Ved. need some time. My webservice server jst got down. not getting any data @Ved

Comment: @Ved I just noticed, I already have this written in IE <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">

Comment: @Ryan.Hunt but its working fine in Chrome

Comment: I cant say than what exactly causing this isse. You can try adding `use strict;` on the top of your controller file.

Comment: already there @Ved

Comment: I have the precisely exactly same issue with the same configuration and no debug error. have you found the solution? thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer myself. Instead of directly putting the interpolation, use

```
<div ng-bind="somefunction(somevalue)"></div>
```

this will bind the result with the div.